# Python to input form data from CSV file to local HTML file

Tags: python, html, forms, input, mechanize

I am currently attempting to write a python script to pull specific data from a locally saved csv file and then input that data to a website and click submit. I have successfully extracted the data but I have been unable to open the file using the mechanize module.

I am open to using a different language if there is another way I just figured that python would have been the simplest way to get this task done. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. 
`

```
import datetime
import webbrowser
import csv
import mechanize


now = datetime.datetime.now()
mont = now.month
mon = mont + 2
with open(r'\\MyDataNEE\user$\bat0km4\Desktop\automation.csv') as f:
    mycsv = csv.reader(f)
    mycsv = list(mycsv)
    osha = mycsv[mon][2]
    occasional = mycsv[mon][3]
    fleet = mycsv[mon][4]
print(osha)
print(occasional)
print(fleet)

url = r"\\mydatanee\user$\bat0km4\Documents\test.html"

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots( False )
br.open(url)



br.form['osh'] = osha
br.form['occasion'] = occasional
br.form['flee'] = fleet

br.submit()
```

`
**UPDATE** : here is my html code in case that could be an issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function show_confirm()
            {
                var r = confirm("Please Confirm that all values are correct. \nPress ok to submit");
                if (r == true)
                {
                    alert(document.getElementById('osh').value + " " + document.getElementById('occasion').value + " " + document.getElementById('flee').value);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

    </script>
    <h1 align="center" style="color: black; font-size: 30pt; font-weight: bolder;">
            Safety Indicator 
    </h1>

    <form name="input" onsubmit="show_confirm();" method = "get">
            <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            OSHA Injuries
                        </td>
                        <td> 
                            <input id = "osh" name="osha" type="text">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Occasional Use Incidents
                        </td>
                        <td> 
                            <input id = "occasion" name="occasional" type="text"> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Fleet Incidents
                        </td>
                        <td> 
                            <input id = "flee" name="fleet" type="text">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE** : I used the file type that was suggested by placing file:// at the front and now I'm getting this error. Is there something that I should be placing in my html file to allow mechanize to do this? 
**Can anyone confirm that mechanize does in fact have the ability to interact with local html files? I am having a hard time finding anyone who is using mechanize in this way**

```
    C:\Python27>python pyth.py
0
1
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyth.py", line 24, in <module>
    br.open(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 254, in open
    return self._mech_open(url_or_request, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 284, in _mech_open
    response = UserAgentBase.open(self, request, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_opener.py", line 195, in open
    response = urlopen(self, req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 352, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 340, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 1324, in file_open
    return self.parent.open(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 254, in open
    return self._mech_open(url_or_request, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 284, in _mech_open
    response = UserAgentBase.open(self, request, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_opener.py", line 195, in open
    response = urlopen(self, req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 352, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 340, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 1384, in ftp_open
    raise URLError('ftp error: no host given')
```

Comment: Please paste errors as code snippets not images

Comment: Add error that you are getting

Comment: The path is local UNC network path. Add `file://` to `url` (not `http`). You may to swap all the slashes to `/`. E.g. `file://///mydatanee/user$/bat0km4/Documents/test.html`

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWERED** I ended up downloading Xampp with which I was able to use apache to just host my html file locally and that solved my problem. I would still like to know if mechanize has the ability to access local html files on their own though.